# Sourcing the `/etc/environment` in Go

Tags: python, regex, go, pattern-matching, environment-variables

I am trying to source the `/etc/environment` file using golang.
I parsed each line of the file and used the following piece of code:

`` var myExp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<first>.*)=(?P<second>.*)`) ``
to get key=value from the file. But some values have `=` in it and the above regex fails.

For example, one of the lines in the environment would look like: 
`CONFIG_BASE64=SDFSWESC1=` and I want it to be separated by the first occurence of `=`. i.e, Key is`CONFIG_BASE64` and Value is `SDFSWESC1=`

Comment: You want to retrieve ``CONFIG_BASE64`` as a key and ``SDFSWESC1=`` as a value from ``CONFIG_BASE64=SDFSWESC1=``. If my understanding is correct, how about this? ``(?P<first>.*?)=(?P<second>.*)``

Comment: Looks like that worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `strings.SplitN()`? Going to regex seems overkill for this.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("/etc/environment")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        // MAGIC
        split := strings.SplitN(scanner.Text(), "=", 2)
        // Line didn't have an = in it
        if len(split) < 2 {
            continue
        }
        // Skip comments, pretty naive though
        if strings.HasPrefix(split[0], "#") {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("key %s value %s\n", split[0], split[1])
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}
```